# When are the values of the ForInit if a StatementExpressionList is used in a for statement discared?

Tags: java, for-loop, initialization, expression

A simple for statement would be:

```
 for(ForInit/*Optional*/; EXPRESSION/*Optional*/; ForUpdate/*Optional*/) {
 }


 ForInit:
 StatmentExpressionList
 LocalVariableDecleration

 StatmentExpressionList
 e.g 
    int i = 0; a = 10, z = 2;
```

Each expression in the sequence is evaluated from left to right and if any expression completes abruptly the for statement completes abruptly and evaluation of the sequence ends from where it has completed. The values of any of the expression which are evaluated left to right are discarded.

Now what would cause the expression to complete abruptly?
At what stage of evaluating each expression in the sequence is the value of that expression discarded, and if the value of that expression is discarded than how does the rest of the for loop execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example for first parameter

```
String a = null;
for (int i = a.length(); i < 5; i++)
```

For the second parameter

```
String a = null;
for (int i = 1; i < a.length(); i++)
```

And for the third (can you guess it?)

```
String a = null;
for (int i = 1; i < 5; a.append(" "));
```

Of course the rest of the loop is not executed.

UPDATE: I interpret the reference to "discarded values" (can't check now) as:

```
int i = 13;
try {
  String a = null;
  for (int i = 1; i < a.length(); i++)
  ...
} catch (Exception e) {
}

// Here i = 13
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14
14.14.1.1: 
If the ForInit code is a list of statement expressions (§14.8), the expressions are evaluated in sequence from left to right; their values, if any, are discarded. When are those values discarded?

Comment: Just a guess but easily verifiable if you are near a java compiler, check the update.

Answer (score 1):

A variant would be:

```
int a = getA(); //returns 0
for (int i = 10 / a; i < 5; i++) { //Ooops
}
```

Comment: So it's safe to say that the values of the expressions in the sequence are discarded if the for statement is interrupted? And the values of the expressions have a life span while the for loop is executing?